# weird postgresql client time shifting issue after laptop standby?

Tags: postgresql

I have run into this weird issue, I use `sqlworkbench/J` (a java client) to connect to a local pg14 database, the laptop is suspended, and in the **morning**, when I run the following query:

```
select current_setting ('TIMEZONE'), current_timestamp, current_timestamp::timestamp;
```

...I received the following result:

> ```
>  current_setting |       current_timestamp       |     current_timestamp      
> -----------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------
>  Asia/Shanghai   | 2022-12-12 17:30:30.425635+08 | 2022-12-12 17:30:30.425635
> ```

But if I open (a new session with) `sudo -u postgres psql`, the same query give me

> ```
>  current_setting |       current_timestamp       |     current_timestamp      
> -----------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------
>  Asia/Shanghai   | 2022-12-13 07:30:36.760764+08 | 2022-12-13 07:30:36.760764
> ```

I also tried `pgmodeler`, the same correct result.

All subsequent query in sqlworkbench/j involving `currenttimestamp`  will yield consistently wrong results (that's how did I noticed this, some of my query involving current_time - some_log_time become negative, which is logically impossible.).
But after I restarted `workbench/j` (maybe a simple reconnect is enough, I regret, I chose to restart in the first place). Everything returned to normal again.

What could be the logic behind such glitch? Isn't `current_timestamp` processed solely on the server side? (I mean whatever happened to workbench/j, in this case, how come the  query even yield negative timedeltas, meaning the server really took current_timestamp as 17:xx on query processing for that sql session, right? meanwhile new sessions are correctly take as 7:xx )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glitch is on your side. The old session started a transaction and kept it open for hours. `current_timestamp` shows the time when you started the transaction, no matter how long the transaction takes.

Perhaps you disabled autocommit in your interactive client. That is a mistake, because it can cause damage to your PostgreSQL database: your transaction could keep autovacuum from cleaning up dead tuples, which can let your tables grow unreasonably if there are many `UPDATE`s.

Comment: Thanks. I always thought `current_timestamp` works as `getdate()` in mssql. After re-consulting  the doc, now I know `current_timestamp` is the alias of `transaction_timestamp()`, and `clock_timestamp()` is the current server time equavalent to `getdate()`. The glitch is indeed on my side, not my sql client :-).